# jquery, using $.each() to add options to a select

Tags: jquery

I'm attempting to populate two `<select>` elements with monthly values. Instead of duplicating the logic for doing so, I'm attempting to use jQuery's `$.each()` to make this happen. Here's some code:

```
for ( var i = 0; i < 12; i++ )
{
  var cm = moment().month(i);
  $( '#m1, #m2' ).each( function( i, el ) {
    $( el ).append( $( "<option />" ) ).val( cm.format( "MM" ) ).text( cm.format( "MMM" ) ) ;
  });
}
```

I think in theory what I'm trying to do is correct, just syntactically not compliant with jQuery. The problem I'm running into is the `option` elements are not being appended. If I replace the `$.each()` code and just the same exact thing for `$( '#m1' )` and `$( '#m2' )` individually, it'll work. So the problem is most likely on how I'm using `$.each()`

This is using jQuery 3.1.0.

Comment: So what's the problem you're running into?

Comment: Updated post to reflect the actual problem, sorry about that.

Comment: You don't need `each()` at all here, you can `append()` to both elements at the same time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the `.val()` and `.text()` assigned to the wrong element.  Your `.append()` line should read as follows:

```
$(el).append( $("<option />").val(cm.format( "MM" )).text(cm.format( "MMM" )) ) ;
```

Similarly, the easiest way would be to avoid the `.each()` loop entirely and just call the `.append()` method:

```
$("#m1, #m2").append( $("<option />").val(cm.format( "MM" )).text(cm.format( "MMM" )) );
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this way

```
for ( var i = 0; i < 12; i++ )
{
  var cm = moment().month(i);
  $( '#m1, #m2' ).append('<option value="'+cm.format( "MM" )+'">'+cm.format( "MMM" )+'</option>"' ) ;
}
```

[Working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/berets/kk7L4aLw/1/)

Or this way if you wanna your style

```
for ( var i = 0; i < 12; i++ )
{
  var cm = moment().month(i);
  $( '#m1, #m2' ).append($('<option/>').val(cm.format( "MM" )).text(cm.format( "MMM" ))) ;
}
```

[Working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/berets/kk7L4aLw/2/)